# serious issue of springcloud hystrix under high concurrency?

Tags: java, spring, hystrix, fallback

## PART1

while i using HystrixCommand for service, and use jmeter to have high concurrency test. The test result is so bad, see flowing.
code->

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "helloFallback")
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseResult hello() throws Exception{
    ResponseResult responseResult = new ResponseResult();
    responseResult.setCode(200);
    responseResult.setData("bank test ok");
    return responseResult;
}
public ResponseResult helloFallback(){
    ResponseResult responseResult = new ResponseResult();
    responseResult.setCode(400);
    responseResult.setData("timeout error");
    return responseResult;
}
```

test reuslt:[jmeter_test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfSAU.png)

## PART2

However, if i comment out the HystrixCommand,the test result is perfect.code->

```
//    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "helloFallback")
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseResult hello() throws Exception{
    ResponseResult responseResult = new ResponseResult();
    responseResult.setCode(200);
    responseResult.setData("bank test ok");
    return responseResult;
}
public ResponseResult helloFallback(){
    ResponseResult responseResult = new ResponseResult();
    responseResult.setCode(400);
    responseResult.setData("timeout error");
    return responseResult;
}
```

test result->[jmeter_test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMD8Z.png)

Tip:the thread pic
[jmeter_test3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dpXB.png)

Whatever i use zuul to forward and call the service directly, the test result are same. So is it the issue of springcloud hystrix while high concurrency or there is some problem with my code. Any reply is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

First, please try to adjust the below properties.

```
hystrix.threadpool.default.coreSize
```

The default thread pool size is just 10 and it's quite small size for your performance test.

In your first test with hystrix, you can see 31% error ratio. It probably means that there could be many thread pool rejections because the default thread pool is only 10.

As you know, Hystrix provides great isolation with circuit breaker and it requires some costs to handle it. So some performance degradation can not be avoidable. But your test result doesn't look normal.

You can find more details about hystrix configuration [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#coreSize)